# How to generate the Azure Table Service SAS token from c# code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I would like to generate the SAS token for Azure table service from C# code. I generated the one from the portal which looks like

```
?sv=2016-05-31&ss=t&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacu&se=2017-03-23T20:05:14Z&st=2017-03-23T12:05:14Z&sip={MY_IP}&spr=https&sig=fL9GNAZqybSlQKWvaspwr%2FrFFtWO%2F5jVgFu1Ayu94Ic%3D
```

How to generate such kind of token from c# code? If there is any tutorial please redirect me to it.
I tried with a method below, but the token generated is invalid.

**UPDATED CODE**

I am still getting an error **403 Forbidden**. Is my code to compute the signature correct?

```
var StringToSign = "{Storage_account_name}" + "\n" +
                            "rwdlacu" + "\n" +
                            "t" + "\n" +
                            "sco" + "\n" +
                            "2017-03-24T12:05:14Z" + "\n" +
                            "2017-03-24T20:05:14Z" + "\n" +
                            "{IP}" + "\n" +
                            "https" + "\n" +
                            "2016-05-31" + "\n";
string encodedString = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(StringToSign);
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String("accountkey"));
var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(encodedString)));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're running into the issue is because you're calculating signature for SAS based on the logic for calculating `Authorization` header. `StringToSign` is different in both cases.

For SAS, this should be (for `Service SAS`):

```
StringToSign = signedpermissions + "\n" +  
               signedstart + "\n" +  
               signedexpiry + "\n" +  
               canonicalizedresource + "\n" +  
               signedidentifier + "\n" +  
               signedIP + "\n" +  
               signedProtocol + "\n" +  
               signedversion + "\n" +  
               startingPartitionKey + "\n"  
               startingRowKey + "\n"  
               endingPartitionKey + "\n"  
               endingRowKey
```

If you want to use `Account SAS` (which is what Portal does), it should be:

```
StringToSign = accountname + "\n" +  
    signedpermissions + "\n" +  
    signedservice + "\n" +  
    signedresourcetype + "\n" +  
    signedstart + "\n" +  
    signedexpiry + "\n" +  
    signedIP + "\n" +  
    signedProtocol + "\n" +  
    signedversion + "\n"
```

So based on your parameters, the StringToSign for Account SAS would be:

```
StringToSign = {youraccountname} + "\n" +  
    "rwdlacu" + "\n" +  
    "t" + "\n" +  
    "sco" + "\n" +  
    "2017-03-23T12:05:14Z" + "\n" +  
    "2017-03-23T20:05:14Z" + "\n" +  
    {yourip} + "\n" +  
    "https" + "\n" +  
    "2016-05-31 + "\n"
```

The computation for `signature` is correct.

You may find these links helpful to learn more about computing SAS: [`Account SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-an-account-sas) and [`Service SAS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/fileservices/constructing-a-service-sas).

**UPDATE**

There's an issue with `hmac` calculation as well. It should be using your account key and also it should use `Convert.FromBase64String`.

```
HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey));
```

Also, you should not URLEncode `StringToSign`. Elements there should be URL decoded.

Lastly the SAS token should look like what you're getting back from the portal.

**Code Sample**

```
    static void AccountSasSample()
    {
        var accountName = "your-account-name";
        var accountKey = "your-account-key";
        var start = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        var end = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1).ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ssZ");
        var permission = "rwdlacu";
        var serviceType = "t";
        var resourceTypes = "sco";
        var ipAddress = "your-ip-address";
        var protocol = "https";
        var serviceVersion = "2016-05-31";
        var stringToSign = string.Format("{0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}\n{4}\n{5}\n{6}\n{7}\n{8}\n", accountName, permission, serviceType, resourceTypes, start, end, ipAddress, protocol, serviceVersion);
        Console.WriteLine(stringToSign);
        HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String(accountKey));
        string signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign)));
        var sasToken = string.Format("?sv={0}&ss={1}&srt={2}&sp={3}&se={4}&st={5}&sip={6}&spr={7}&sig={8}", serviceVersion,
            serviceType, resourceTypes, permission, end, start, ipAddress, protocol, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(signature));
        Console.WriteLine(sasToken);
        var urlToListTables = string.Format("https://{0}.table.core.windows.net/Tables{1}", accountName, sasToken);
        //Copy this urlToListTables & paste it in browser's address bar. You should be able to see the list of tables in your storage account.
    }
```

Comment: I am still getting an error **403 Forbidden**. Is my code to compute the signature correct? **I have updated the code in the asked question**.

Comment: There's an issue with signature calculation as well. Let me edit my answer.

Comment: Yes, I am formatting the string correctly, but even after accommodating your suggested change of `HMACSHA256 hmac = new HMACSHA256(Convert.FromBase64String("account key");` I am getting **403 Forbidden** error.

Comment: Your code above is still URL encoding the StringToSign. You need not do this.

Comment: Can you provide me with the sample? I am getting confused with what to encode and what to convert to hmac?

Comment: I don't blame you :). You miss one minor thing and you get this 403 error. Let me work out a sample for you.

Comment: Updated my answer with sample code. Please change the values for account name, key and your IP address. Once you copy `urlToListTables` value and paste in browser's address bar, you should be able to see the list of tables in your storage account. HTH.

Answer (score 5):

```
//account name               
var storageAccountName = ConfigProvider.AccountName;
// your storage account access key here
var accessKey = ConfigProvider.BlobKey;

// connect to our storage account and create a blob client
var connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1}",
    storageAccountName,
    accessKey);
var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connectionString);
var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

SharedAccessAccountPolicy policy = new SharedAccessAccountPolicy()
{
    Permissions = SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Write | SharedAccessAccountPermissions.Create,
    Services = SharedAccessAccountServices.Blob,
    ResourceTypes = SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Container | SharedAccessAccountResourceTypes.Object,
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(1),
    Protocols = SharedAccessProtocol.HttpsOnly,
};

string sasToken = storageAccount.GetSharedAccessSignature(policy);
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use Azure Storage Client Library to generate SAS? You can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1